# Form contents in VB 2019 is not visible

Tags: vb.net

[image: form hidden]

Why I cannot see the form contains in VB2019?

Comment: That is the "Binary Editor" that you are seeing.  While it is possible that you somehow selected that editor as the default instead of the "Visual Basic Form Editor" (right-click on the file in the Solution Explorer and select "Open With"), the disturbing issue is that the file contents consists  entirely of null characters.  Apparently, something overwrote the file.

Comment: What is the "form contains" that you want to see?

Comment: The file can’t be opened with the selected editor. please select anther editor --- this the massage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say why that has happened but I have seen it myself or from other people from time to time. That it seems to have happened to so many of your forms suggest that something catastrophic happened to your project and corrupted a bunch of files. One thing that has worked for me in the past is as follows:

1. Add a new project to your solution.
2. Drag a corrupted for to the new project in the Solution Explorer.
3. Do as required to make the new project build and run. The form hopefully now works in the new project.
4. Delete the original form from the original project.
5. Drag the form from the new project back to the original project. The form hopefully now works in the original project.
6. Delete the new project when all forms have been repaired.

The corrupted form resources seem to be regenerated when creating a copy in the new project as this has worked for me and others, although I'm not sure that it will always be so.